# How to do qiuck lookup using EnumMap in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have about 30 handler routines to dispatch when given a routine name, in String form.
So in a factory method, a natural way to dispatch routine is using a series of `if...else` to compare the routine name to fit in the slot. it works, but no doubt it is clumsy and inefficient as the number of routines rises up.

I came up with a fashion using enum and EnumMap:  whenever I add a routine, I add an enum instance, and register it in EnumMap(the routine name and the routine class as key and value).

As what I know, when the number of instances is less than **64(the long type length)**, the EnumMap implementation uses a `long` as a **bit array** and use bit offset to do `put` and `get`, so it is extremely fast, and I could gain a O(1) performance when I dispatch the routine as long as  the number of routine is less than 64(it quite suits for my situation).

However, a limit of **EnumMap** is that its `key type` can only be a `Enum`, instead of `String`, 
and I could not use the routine name(`string`) to do a quick lookup....

Is there any way to work around this ?
Or if only I could do a reverse lookup using a value for a key :)

Comment: Why not to use `HashMap`? Is it too slow for you?

Comment: Why are you given a routine name in String form? Is it possible to use polymorphic methods and avoid the whole problem?

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov, actually I now use it, and I just wanna know how about EnumMap, uh.. maybe it isn't a good choice.

Comment: @EJP, yep, that is an elegent OOP way, but I have no control on the other part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it simple and just use a `HashMap<String, Handler>` until you can prove that this is a serious bottleneck. I'm assuming here that there's a common superclass or interface that all your handlers extend, so you can just do

```
handlers.get(name).handle(...);
```

EnumMap won't be any faster if you're starting from a String key as you first have to use `valueOf` to get the enum value corresponding to the string, and [this is itself implemented as a lookup in a HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java#Enum.valueOf%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.String%29)...